# How to close tabs to the right using vimperator?

Tags: firefox, vimperator

I'm using Firefox, and installed vimperator. It's great, but I can't found the method to close tabs to the right using hotkey. Could you please tell me how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, my question is not clear, I mean that how to config hotkey to replace to click "Close Tabs To The Right" menu item at current tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Close all to right/left.

Place the following code in your `.vimperatorrc` file. It defines commands `:closealltoright` and `:closealltoleft` as well as bindings <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>></kbd> and <kbd>v</kbd><kbd><</kbd> respectively. Change the bindings as desired in the lines beginning "map" towards the bottom.

```
js <<EOF

closeAllToRight = function () {
    var current = tabs.getTab();
    var currentIx = tabs.index(current);
    var nexttab = current.nextElementSibling;
    var N = tabs.count;
    var numToClose = N - (currentIx + 1);
    tabs.remove(nexttab, numToClose);
}

closeAllToLeft = function () {
    var current = tabs.getTab();
    var currentIx = tabs.index(current);
    var firsttab = tabs.getTab(0);
    var N = tabs.count;
    var numToClose = currentIx;
    tabs.remove(firsttab, numToClose);
}

EOF

" close tabs to left
map v< :js closeAllToLeft()<CR>
" close tabs to right
map v> :js closeAllToRight()<CR>

command! closealltoright :js closeAllToRight()
command! closealltoleft :js closeAllToLeft()
```

I've uploaded these two commands as a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/troyp/20e4b1f744c5e799f1df).

---

#### Pentadactyl version.

```
command! closetabstoleft
    \ -description "Close all tabs to the left of the current tab"
    \ -js
    \ var firstTab = tabs.getTab(0);
    \ var numToClose = tabs.getTab().dactylOrdinal - 1;
    \ tabs.remove(firstTab, numToClose);
command! closetabstoright
    \ -description "Close all tabs to the right of the current tab"
    \ -js
    \ tabIndex = tabs.getTab().dactylOrdinal - 1;
    \ var nextTabIndex = tabIndex + 1;
    \ var firstTab = tabs.getTab(nextTabIndex);
    \ var N = tabs.allTabs.length;
    \ var numToClose = N - nextTabIndex;
    \ tabs.remove(firstTab, numToClose);

map v< -ex closetabstoleft
map v> -ex closetabstoright
```

I've placed these in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/troyp/6a5669785a25f626866bd1398ff422a6) for convenience.

Further tab commands can be found in my [Pentadactyl folder](https://github.com/troyp/.pentadactyl) (the commands and bindings are in `.pentadactylrc`, but may rely on functions defined in `utils.js`).

Comment: @pyrocrasty Do you know where I can find vimperator API ? I mean you are using such elements as 'tabs', 'tabs.remove' etc. Where are they documented?

Comment: @ka3ak: I'm afraid they're not. You have to look in the source and/or explore interactively from the command-line. Stuff like tab and buffer functions are easy. Just type `tabs.` or `buffers.` on the command-line and use tab completion to see what methods are available. Other things are hard to work out without an overall understanding of the (undocumented) vimperator/dactyl architecture. It's probably a bit easier if you're experienced with webdev (or better, FF extension dev), but I'm not. If I need something, it's usually a hit-and-miss matter of source-grepping and cmdline trial-and-error.

Comment: @ka3ak: you can check out my .pentadactyl folder (linked in the answer) to see how to do some stuff I've worked out (esp the `.pentadactylrc` and `utils.js` files). Unfortunately, the code may need modification to work on vimperator. Often it's fairly simple (like changing `dactyl.` to `liberator.`), but sometimes it may be harder. I do have a [`.vimperatorrc`](https://github.com/troyp/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimperatorrc) file, but there's not much in it.

Comment: correction: in my comment above, `buffers.` should be `buffer.`

Answer (score 0):

Add `map <your_key_binding> gt :bd -s left<CR>` to your vimperatorrc.

**Explanation:**

`gt` switches to the next right tab, `:bd -s left` deletes this tab and switches after that to the left tab.

Comment: Sorry, my question is not clear, I mean that how to config hotkey to replace to click "Close Tabs To The Right" menu item at current tab.